# Using Firebase Cloud Functions, can I schedule updates from an external API to update Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. Using cloud functions, is there a way to fetch API data without axios? Is there a way to get this data inside a scheduled pubsub function?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });


exports.getVehicles = functions.https.onCall((req:any, res:any) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.method !== "GET") {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Not allowed"
      });
    }
    return axios.get('https://api.zubiecar.com/api/v2/zinc/vehicles', {
              method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Zubie-Api-Key": "123456789"
         },
     })
        .then((response:any) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: response.data.ip
          })
        })
        .catch((err:any) => {
          return res.status(500).json({
            error: err
          })
        })
  
    })
  });


  exports.updateDriverLocation = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async(context:any) => {
    
    //return array of driver objects from api
    const update = await getVehicles();

    //database
    const DB = admin.firestore()
    const REF = DB.collection("drivers")
    const BATCH = DB.batch()  
    
    //update firestore with api response
    update.forEach((vehicle:any) => {
        BATCH.set( REF.doc(vehicle.nickname),
          {vehicle},
          { merge: true }
        )
    })
    await BATCH.commit()
    return null;
  });
```

Essentially, I'm looking to keep my Firestore database in sync with the Zubie API, which updates vehicle locations every two minutes. Alternatively, I am using nextJS and exploring the use of useSWR to accomplish these updates when a page loads. However, that is presenting its own challenges also.

**ANSWER**

```
const getVehicles = async () => {
  let url = `https://api.zubiecar.com/api/v2/zinc/vehicles`
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Zubie-Api-Key':'fooBar',
    },
  })
  const json = await response.json()
  return json
}

exports.updateVehicles = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 5 minutes')
  .onRun(async () => {
    const DB = admin.firestore()
    const REF = DB.collection('drivers')
    const BATCH = DB.batch()
    const {vehicles} = await getVehicles()
    for (const key in vehicles) {
      const vehicle = vehicles[key]
      const {nickname} = vehicle
      BATCH.set(REF.doc(nickname), {vehicle}, {merge: true})
    }
    await BATCH.commit()
    return
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using cloud functions, is there a way to fetch API data without axios?

If you want to access some API, you'll have to write that code yourself.  Cloud Functions will not do that for you.  Cloud Functions is just a hosted container that runs your code when triggered.

> Is there a way to get this data inside a scheduled pubsub function?

Sure, you can write a scheduled function to trigger periodically, and you can have that code access the API.  That should be no more difficult than what you have now.  You can reuse almost all the code.

> Essentially, I'm looking to keep my Firestore database in sync with the Zubie API, which updates vehicle locations every two minutes.

You can only run scheduled functions at most every 5 minutes.  It can't be configured to run more frequently.

Comment: I will keep trying, I don't understand how to call "exports.getVehicles" from inside the pubsub. Or better yet, I don't understand how to reWrite "exports.getVehicles" into a function without the parameters "(req:any, res:any)"

Comment: That sounds like a completely different problem than the one you've posted here.  If you have a new question, post that separately.  Be sure to limit yourself to one question per post, otherwise it might get closed as "needs focus".